# Python Selenium No Such Element, No iFrame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm relatively new to using python & selenium. I'm trying to access NexisUni to automate a loop of searches. But, once I'm in NexisUni, I struggle to locate elements -- I get a "no such element" exception. I want to locate the search bar and input my search terms.

I've read about the fact that an iFrame might be present, and I need to switch frames. But, I don't see any frames! Is there a way to identify frames easily -- and could a frame be present without the word "frame" in the HTML? I've also tried loading the page longer and having the driver wait, to no avail.

The HTML code is below, the grey part is the piece I'd like to select:

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ3v5.png)

The code I'm writing to identify it is:

```
SearchBar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[13]/div[2]/div[1]/header/div[3]/section/span[2]/span/textarea').send_keys('search text')
```

I've also tried these two options:

```
find_element_by_class_name, find_element_by_id

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located)
```

... Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: @coderoftheday He has already tried that.`I've also tried these two options:

find_element_by_class_name, fi`  `find_element_by_id`

Comment: didn't see thanks @AbrarAhmed

Comment: Yes, I tried that already, sorry the question wasn't clear -- just edited!

Comment: If you've tried by id, or the xpath with id (//textarea[@id='searchTerms']) and there is no element to be found, it points to an iframe, but you say there is no iframe in the DOM? More of the HTML may help us confirm.